# Why can't I assign a "protected" modifier to a "friend" property in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

The following doesn't compile:

```
MustInherit Class Foo
    Friend Property objects As List(Of Object)
        Get
            Return _objects
        End Get
        Protected Set(value As List(Of Object))
            _objects = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Property _objects As New List(Of Object)
End Class
```

I'm getting the error message: `Access modifier 'Protected Friend' is not valid. The access modifier of 'Get' and 'Set' should be more restrictive than the property access level.`. Well, it is more restrictive. Only subclasses of `Foo` in the same assembly could set this property.

Why is this not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, it is more restrictive. Only subclasses of Foo in the same assembly could set this property.

No, that's not true. [`Protected Friend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx) means that anyone in the assembly, and also anyone derived from the class (outside of the current assembly), can call the property. That is, it's an "or" operation, not an "and". VB.Net does not have the "protected and friend" access specifier you're looking for; only "protected or friend".

Comment: Good answer. I'll just declare `_objects` protected, `objects` as `ReadOnly`, and `Foo` as `Friend`.